# Validation message not showing for property of sub class of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Model:

```
public class Person : IValidatableObject
{
    public Address ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
    public Address PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
}
```

in Model:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PostalAddress.Address1))
     {
          yield return
                  new ValidationResult("Postal address is required",
                      new[] { nameof(PostalAddress.Address1) });
     }
}
```

View: **(A partial view for address inside the View for Person)**

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address1)
```

In the html this comes out with the name `PostalAddress.Address1` and the id `PostalAddress_Address1`

Unfortunately `nameof(PostalAddress.Address1)` just returns `Address1`.

I have tried replacing it with `PostalAddress.Address1` and `PostalAddress_Address1` and can't get the error to show up.

What's the secret?

Comment: Your model need to implement `IValidatableObject`

Comment: Person is actually a viewmodel, it's simplified for the question. The validation is working, I just want to know how to get the error to display...

Answer (score 0):

I think @MikeDebela is right in the comment below your answer. Your model needs to implement `IValidatableObject` if you're going to use custom model validation like that. However, that's not your only problem.

First, is there a particular reason you're not just relying on the `[Required]` attribute for this? Custom model validation is a bit of a waste for something this simple. If the issue is that this is your actual entity class, and you don't want the `Address1` column non-nullable at the database-level, well, that's what view models are for. Use them. You can make the property required on just your view model. As a best practice, you should never utilize your entity classes directly to post to.

Also, you're never newing up `PostalAddress`. When the model binder does its thing on post, if no properties of a related class are posted, it leaves the value of the that related class as `null`. Then, any related classes that are null, are also not validated. As a result, if the only property is `Address1` and you don't post `Address1`, then `PostalAddress` is `null`, and no property on it, specifically, `Address1`, will participate in validation.

Comment: I cannot use the Required attribute because it's not always required, PostalAddress.Address1 is only required when ResidentialAddress.Address1 is not set.

Comment: I am not in control of the database

Comment: Also I am implementing : IValidatableObject but forgot to add it to the example code sorry

Comment: All the more reason to be using view models. That way, you can leave the entity alone entirely, and still do whatever your application requires.

Comment: I could add a view model..but would still have the same problem. The logic is not going to change.